# Swift - "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am having a lot of trouble trying to decode this `JSON` with Swift 4.2:

```
{
    token = a3253e6ade9b5c7fd99673938bb28b3e;
    user =     {
        "about_me" = Admin;
        address = "";
        "banner_path" = "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/008/1540737652129.jpg?1541043871";
        company = "<null>";
        description = "<null>";
        email = "admin@stf.com";
        "events_count" = 0;
        "followers_count" = 0;
        "following_count" = 0;
        id = 2;
        "image_path" = "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/009/1540737834886.jpg?1541043896";
        "is_admin" = 1;
        major = "";
        "my_post_count" = 5;
        name = "Admin MemberPortal";
        "non_business_email" = "<null>";
        passedout = "";
        "phone_number" = 000000000;
        photos =         (
            "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/004/IMG_20181029_150700.jpg?1540805844",
            "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/012/20181028_173702.jpg?1541126171",
            "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/011/20181028_173703.jpg?1541126151",
            "http://members.sharjahcd.ae/images/000/000/010/20181028_173705.jpg?1541126144"
        );
        position = "<null>";
        role = Admin;
        stars = 3;
        "total_membership_points" = 0;
    };
}
```

Here how am trying to decode it

```
let UserDatas = try JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: data)
  print("response : \(UserDatas)")


struct Token: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let user: [Response]
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let about_me: String
    let address: String
    let company: String
    let description: String
    let email: String
    let events_count: Int
    let followers_count: Int
    let following_count: Int
    let id = Int()
    let image_path: String
    let is_admin: String
    let major: String
    let my_post_count: Int
    let name: String
    let non_business_email: String
    let passedout: String
    let phone_number: Int
    let photos: [String]
    let position: String
    let role: String
    let stars: Int
    let total_membership_points: Int
}
```

It doesn't work and got the following error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

How do I make a struct that will decode this JSON?

Comment: what you have shown is not JSON. JSON does not use `=` between the property name and its value. Nor does it use `(` and `)` to represent the beginning and end of arrays. Possibly your code cannot decode it because it's not actually JSON.

Comment: Also, you've shown a different error message in the question title and in the main question. That's a bit confusing. Can you clarify what the real error is, please.

Comment: it actually the raw value of the response

Comment: response from where? If that is the literal string you're getting back from some API, then you have a problem because it's not valid JSON, and no JSON parser will be able to decode it.

Comment: Alamofire.request(urlString, parameters: userCount)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    guard let result = response.data else { return }
                    print("success\(response)")
                    completion(.success(result))
                } else {
                    print("Error")
                    if let error = response.result.error{
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
        }

Comment: here the success response am getting the values like that

Comment: @ADyson It seems to be the print of a Swift Dictionary, obtained through `JSONSerialization` (what should do Alamofire). Nothing complicated. To answer the question, `let user: [Response]` should be `let user: Response`.

Comment: @Larme thanks, I'm not a swift developer, just saw the question through the JSON tag. But OP appeared to be claiming it was the _raw_ response, so I based my comment on that...also I commented before the Alamofire code was added.

Comment: Did that also in that case am getting error like this valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "company", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: If you get the *valueNotFound / found null* error, make the struct member optional: `let company: String?`

Comment: `company` value is `null` as you can see. You need to use an Optional to reflect that as said by @vadian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, the user property isn't an array, but you have it declared as an Array (`[Response]`) in your code. Change your code to:

```
struct Token: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let user: Response
}
```

Also, if you have any properties declared in your code that's null or missing from your JSON, you should make them optional.

In your JSON, company seems to be null, so change

```
let company: String
```

to

```
let company: String?
```

And do the same for other properties that might be null or missing.

Comment: Yeah trying changing all the values based on your answer

Comment: Thanks man now its working after changing the optional value and types

Comment: Thanks for your time am going to accept your answer

Comment: You can't guarantee that every field goint to be non-null so you should make all your fields optional. So when your web servis API returns an invalid or corrupted response your application won't crash.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use `CodingKey`'s.

```
struct Landmark: Codable {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int
    var location: Coordinate
    var vantagePoints: [Coordinate]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "title"
        case foundingYear = "founding_date"

        case location
        case vantagePoints
    }
}
```

See: [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#2904057)